# optional argument Python

Tags: python, debugging, arguments, option-type

Have to write some code that defines a function that will work with two or three arguments.

The function should take three parameters:

- temperature, a float
- weather, a string
- is_celsius, a boolean

The function should return True if temperature is below
freezing (32 if is_celsius is False, 0 if is_celsius is
True) or if weather is "snowy". Otherwise, it should
return False.

Note, however, that is_celsius should be an optional
argument. If the function call does not supply a value for
is_celsius, assume it is True.

I wrote this

```
def snowed_in(temperature, weather, **cels):
    if weather =="snowy":
        return True
    elif weather=="sunny":
        if 'is_celsius = False' in cels:
            if temperature<32:
                return True
    elif 'is_celsius = True' in cels:
        if temperature<0:
            print ('ad')    
            return True
    elif 'is_celsius = True' not in cels:
        if temperature<0:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

and for the following calls

```
print(snowed_in(15, "sunny")) #Should print False
print(snowed_in(15, "sunny",is_celsius = False)) #Should print True
print(snowed_in(15, "snowy",is_celsius = True)) #Should print True
```

I'm getting

```
None
None
True
```

Can someone help me find what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please post your code exactly as you are running it, including the indentation. What you have posted there is not valid indentation.

Comment: Do you have to pass **cels in parameters ??

Comment: @WajihKatrou there's an easier way to do it. See my answer

Comment: @mrbros35 I asked him because I was thinking of your solution if is not obliged to use **cels in params

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code so as to make a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: hi all, thanks for your comments! alaniwi's response nailed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a situation where it makes sense to use `**kwargs` - that would normally be used for wrapper functions.

You should simply do something like this to declare `is_celsius` explicitly as an optional argument:

```
def snowed_in(temperature, weather, is_celsius=True):
    if weather == "snowy":
        return True
    elif is_celsius:
        return temperature < 0
    else:
        return temperature < 32
```

However, if there is some good reason to capture optional arguments in a dictionary (maybe you also need to pass it to a function that you are wrapping), then you could extract the relevant parameter using `get` with any default value (otherwise it will default to `None`):

```
def snowed_in(temperature, weather, **kwargs):
    if weather == "snowy":
        return True
    elif kwargs.get('is_celsius', True):
        return temperature < 0
    else:
        return temperature < 32
```

Comment: wow... I wished I had known things could be that simple! your first code worked like a charm. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things here, so let me post an edit to your code and step through the changes with you :)

```py
def snowed_in(temperature, weather, cels=True):
    if weather =="snowy":
        return True
    elif weather=="sunny":
        if not cels:
            if temperature<32:
                return True
    elif cels:
        if temperature<0:
            print ('ad')    
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Boolean expressions**

You input `is_celsius` as a boolean but evaluate it as a string which is more than a little odd.

Instead of trying to match a specific string i.e. `'is_celsius = True' in cels:`, you can just check the state of the boolean 'cels' ie `if cels:`

**Default arguments**

*If the function call does not supply a value for is_celsius, assume it is True.*... python function arguments can have default values.

So using `cels=True` is preferable to `**cels` for your desired behaviour.

Now, `cels=True` will be passed to the function if `cels` is not specified in the function call.

**Syntax**

If you're new to Python [check out PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The point here is that you should try not to have spaces between a variable name, and it's value, in the function arguments i.e `cels=True` not `cels = True`.

**Indentation**

I'm assuming this was an artifact of you copy pasting your code. But! Note that indentation is super important in python. Note the difference between your code and my example above... it's good practice to ensure your code has proper indentation if you're copy pasting it into to stack overflow / somewhere else. Makes it easier for others to read!

Good luck out there!

Comment: thank you so much for your thoughtful response! yes, I'm very new to this, I appreciate the information you provided.