# Do sth specific if an optional parameter (TRUE) is passed in the function call

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm coding a function for freecodecamp and I can't quite figure out how to pass a second optional argument (in this case it has to be True) and print something different depending if the optional arg is present or not.

instructions are : Create a function that receives a list of strings that are arithmetic problems and returns the problems arranged vertically and side-by-side. The function should optionally take a second argument. When the second argument is set to `True`, the answers should be displayed.

PS: I don't want to cheat, just can't figure out the 2nd arg part

I tried using

`def arithmetic_arranger(problems, *args):`

but I don't know how to use the conditional to indicate the function to show the result if 2nd arg is True

code so far is [https://github.com/Tarufetti/practica-public-/blob/f4a5e09c7f755d50b588575c6199188470408da9/arithmetic_formatter(NEWedit)]

Comment: Asterisk notation is when you want to allow _any_ number of parameters. It isn't for optional parameters. Also, your question must be self-contained (we should not have to visit an external link to see your code) Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: So sorry to bother you. if the function call has only the list of problems (and nothing else), won't python show the 'missing one argument' error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [optional argument Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826483/optional-argument-python)

Comment: @Alejandro No, it won't. That's what the default value is for.

Comment: How have you called the function (please provide a self-contained [mre])

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm sorry. I'm new to SO and I am yet to undestand the way things are done here. Thanks for the help. I promise to take the tour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, bool_var=False):
    if bool_var:
       #do something if an optional True argument is passed
```